# Excel Spreadsheet to HTML Programmactically

Tags: html, winforms, excel, xslt, xls

I have a question that I hope someone can answer.  I am using .Net 3.5 Winforms and the SpreadSheetGear 2010 component and need to know if there is a free or low cost method to convert an Excel Workbook to HTML?  Is there a good XSLT transform or some low cost or open source component?  I can save the Excel file to OpenXMLWorkbook programmactically but the component does not allow to save to html.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.Net and follow the code demonstrated by the [Excel to DataGrid Samples](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/datagrid.aspx).  You can always include a reference to `System.Web` in your project.

But, even without ASP.Net, and sticking with the .Net client profile, generating an HTML table from a `DataTable` is simple. Use the [AntiXss Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx) ([download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589)) to encode the data to html.  Then construct your HTML with a `StringBuilder`.  Here's an extension method you can use to convert any `DataTable` to an html `<table>`:

```csharp
using AntiXss = Microsoft.Security.Application;

...

public static String ToHTML(this DataTable dt)
{
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder("<table><thead><tr>");
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>",
            AntiXss.Encoder.HtmlEncode(col.ColumnName));
    }
    html.Append("</tr></thead><tbody>");
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (var data in row.ItemArray)
        {
            html.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>",
                AntiXss.Encoder.HtmlEncode(data.ToString()));
        }
        html.Append("</tr>");
    }
    html.Append("</tbody></table>");
    return html.ToString();
}
```

And to get html for an entire workbook, another extension method:

```csharp
public static List<String> ToHTML(this IWorkBook wb)
{
    List<String> tables = new List<String>();
    DataSet ds = wb.GetDataSet(GetDataFlags.FormattedText);
    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        tables.Add(dt.ToHTML());
    }
    return tables;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but our system is a winforms only system.

Comment: @GregWilliams - I've updated my answer with a solution that doesn't require `System.Web`.